# How to properly resize parent view based on sub-views? (UITableViewCell containing UITextView, for example)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextview

In my case, how would I resize a `UITableViewCell` to accomodate the height of a `UITextView` that it contains?

I'm currently trying to achieve this using the following code:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // init the font that we use
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:16];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        // get the text size of the thread
        CGSize textSize = [_thread.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        return textSize.height + 20;

    }

    // default
    return 60;

}
```

I feel like if I could just get access to the `UITableViewCell` in this method, then I could use the `contentSize` property of the `UITextView` in it, and return that. But I don't think that's possible at this point in the execution flow.

I can't just tweak that buffer, because it doesn't scale with the text size being returned by the get size function. The shorter the text, the more visible a larger buffer size is.

This is adjusting the height of the `UITableViewCell`, but it's not showing all of the `UITextView` inside of it. I've specified the width of the `UITextView` in the `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method, which is `280`. I've specified that I wish to have essentially no maximum height, so that it can word-wrap as much as it needs to, using the `CGFLOAT_MAX` constant. I append a buffer of `20` units to the resulting height of the method call, because there is a `20` unit buffer above the `UITextView`, in my `Storyboard`, and I'd like to also have a `20` unit buffer below it.

The end result of all of this still has text being clipped off, though. Here is a picture of what I am talking about:

[image: clipped cell contents]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer my question. The answer to this comes in two steps.

First, adjust the size of the `UITextView` during your logic inside of the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Make sure to do this *after* making any changes to the text in the `UITextView`. I re-size my `UITextView` using the following method, inside of a subclass of `UITableViewCell` where `self.text` is the text view:

```
- (void)resizeTextView {

    // get the current frame size
    CGRect frame = self.text.frame;

    // set it to the height of the text view
    frame.size.height = self.text.contentSize.height;

    // set the new size of the text view
    self.text.frame = frame;

}
```

Next, I specify the height of the `UITableViewCell` inside of the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexpath:` method. This is where most of the mystery exists, because to get the height for this row you have to calculate the height of any text that is going to be displayed in the row, along with anything else you need to calculate the height of. In my scenario, is was a `UITextView`. Without access to the `UITableViewCell` instance in this method, you're forced to use something like `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`. But, I noticed this was not returning consistent heights for me. Or at least, not heights that seemed to make enough room for my text from the `UITextView`. That was the problem, though. The text view has additional left and right padding as well as different line heights, or something, than the `sizeWithFont` method uses.

So, after fudging the results of the `sizeWithFont` method for awhile, I ended up with the following code:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // init the font that we use
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:16];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        // get the text size of the thread
        CGSize textSize = [_thread.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280 - 16, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        // text height + padding
        return textSize.height + 40;

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        // get the comment for this row
        Comment *comment = [_comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // get the heights of the text areas
        CGSize textSize = [comment.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280 - 16, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        return textSize.height + 40;

    }

    return 60;

}
```

In the size constraint parameter, I subtract 16 units because the `UITextView` has a padding of roughly 8 units on both the left and right sides. This will give us a closer result to what we expected for the height of the text.

I also add some padding to the final height, of 40 units, because the row itself needs some padding around the `UITextView`.

There you go! Hope that helps.